# Window function to select the name of the majority row in Redshift Postgres

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a dataset like this where some rows are useful, but corrupted.

```
create table pages (
  page varchar,
  cat varchar,
  hits int
);

insert into pages values
(1, 'asdf', 1),
(1, 'fdsa', 2),
(1, 'Apples', 321),
(2, 'gwegr', 30),
(2, 'hsgsdf', 2),
(2, 'Bananas', 321);
```

I want to know the correct category for each page, and the total hits. The correct category is the one with the most hits. 
I'd like to have a dataset like:

```
page | category | sum_of_hits
-----------------------------
1    | Apples   |  324
2    | Bananas  |  353
```

The furthest I can get is:

```
SELECT page,
       last_value(cat) over (partition BY page ORDER BY hits) as category,
       sum(hits) as sum_of_hits
FROM pages
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

But it is erroring: `ERROR: column "pages.hits" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 83`.

I tried putting the hits in an aggregate - `ORDER BY max(hits)` but that doesn't make sense and isn't what I want.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cb3c2/17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

First is the usage of the last_value. Read a note in the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) about the last value:

> Note that first_value, last_value, and nth_value consider only the
>   rows within the "window frame", which by default contains the rows
>   from the start of the partition through the last peer of the current
>   row. This is likely to give unhelpful results for nth_value and
>   particularly last_value. You can redefine the frame as being the whole
>   partition by adding ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED
>   FOLLOWING to the OVER clause. See Section 4.2.8 for more information.

I recommend you convert it to first_value:

```
SELECT page,
       first_value(cat) over (partition BY page ORDER BY hits DESC) as category,
       hits
FROM pages
```

The second problem is that you can't use the window function directly in the GROUP BY clause, you need to use a subquery or a cte:

```
select page, category,
       sum(hits)
from (
SELECT page,
       first_value(cat) over (partition BY page ORDER BY hits DESC) as category,
       hits
FROM pages
) a
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c24d4/7)

Answer (score 1):

Use the window function `first_value()` over the reversed order of `hits` in a derived table (a subquery in FROM clause):

```
select 
    page, 
    category,
    sum(hits) as sum_of_hits
from (
    select
        page,
        first_value(cat) over (partition by page order by hits desc) as category,
        hits
    from pages
    ) s
group by 1, 2
order by 1;
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cb3c2/39)

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
select page, cat, hits from
    (select page, cat, hits 
     ,max(hits) over (partition by page) as m_hits 
     from pages) t
where m_hits = hits
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to take the sum of hits *and* the maximum.  This is easy enough:

```
select page, sum(hits) as total_hits,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then category end) as category
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by page order by hits desc) as seqnum
      from pages p
     ) p
group by page;
```